# Spring boot require authorization at context root

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm in the process of researching Spring Boot for a project, and have run into a curious issue with Spring Security. The application is configured to require authentication for all URLs via the following Java configuration:

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .authenticated()
```

I've confirmed that this works fine for most views: attempting to access localhost:8080/test results in a redirect to the login page, which denies access until after logging in (after which it works fine). However, when I access the view registered at the context root (localhost:8080/), this does not happen; I simply receive the view. This outcome is not what I expect, especially since another test application written with the traditional Spring XML configuration can successfully require authentication at the context root with the following line:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

I can conceive of a few workarounds (simplest probably being a redirect header in the root view), but it seems that the path of least resistance would be correctly configuring Spring Security- what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: As mentioned in a below comment, I have tried .anyRequest(), .regexMatchers(".*"), and various patterns for .antMatchers() including ** and /, and none seem to have any effect on the context root itself.

Edit 2: I've now also successfully deployed the war-packaged application to a non-embedded Tomcat, and am experiencing the same issue; this appears to indicate the issue is not exclusive to the embedded Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured this thing out, and I feel kind of like an idiot. For posterity, here was my actual issue:

I had created a login form and logout process using the following code:

```
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .loginPage("/auth")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
                .permitAll()
```

What I didn't realize was that the .permitAll() applied to ALL URLs within the login and logout declarations: /login, /auth, /logout, and /. Once I commented out .permitAll() in both declarations and added the former three in the initial .antMatchers(), all paths including the context root correctly require authentication.